# Repeating calculations in Python

Tags: python-3.x

I have the following code in Python

```
from math import e

def f(x):
    return x*(x+1)

def derivative(x):
    h = 1*e-2
    rise = f(x+h) - f(x)
    run = h
    slope = rise/run
    return slope
```

I want to repeat the calculation for multiple values of `h`, and have all these values displayed when I run the program.

Comment: That's nice. So what's the question? And yeah welcome to [so].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should modify your `derivative` function to accept two parameters - `x` and `h`.

```
def f(x):
    return x*(x+1)

def derivative(x, h):
    rise = f(x+h) - f(x)
    run = h
    slope = rise/run
    return slope
```

Then, use a loop or something:

```
hs = [1,2,3,4]
x = 7
for h in hs:
    print(derivative(x, h))
```

Result:

```
16.0
17.0
18.0
19.0
```